# How can I count rows based on different conditions in the same Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to count the number of items the customer has bought and also count the number of orders the customer has given.
The problem I am facing is that the query counts the numbers of items bought by the customer but it is displaying `Total_Orders = 1`, when I remove `DISTINCT` it returns TOTAL_ORDERS equal to ITEMS.

```
--QUANTITY OF ITEMS BOUGHT AND ORDERS GIVEN BY CUSTOMER
SELECT
    C.FIRST_NAME,
    C.LAST_NAME,
    C.PHONE,
    COUNT(ST.BARCODE) AS ITEMS,
    COUNT(DISTINCT (O.ORDER_DATE)) AS TOTAL_ORDERS,
    C.CUST_ADD_DATE
FROM
    CUSTOMER AS C
    INNER JOIN SALES AS S ON S.CUSTOMER_PHONE = C.PHONE
    INNER JOIN STOCKS AS ST ON ST.INVOICE_ID = S.INVOICE_ID
    INNER JOIN ORDERS AS O ON O.CUSTOMER_ID = C.PHONE
GROUP BY
    C.FIRST_NAME,
    C.LAST_NAME,
    C.PHONE,
    C.CUST_ADD_DATE,
    O.ORDER_ID
```

I need to write this query in Java Swing to populate my table correctly.

```
Object[] row = {
rs.getString("FIRST_NAME") ,
rs.getString("LAST_NAME"), 
rs.getString("PHONE"),
rs.getString("ITEMS"),
rs.getString("TOTAL_ORDERS"),
rs.getDate("CUST_ADD_DATE")
};
```

Comment: Perhaps you should be counting distinct order ids, as opposed to order dates, but hard to tell without seeing sample data, expected results, and actual results. Also, your are grouping on order id, which means you will get 1 back for each order, so you really should not group on that field if you want to get count of orders by customers.

Comment: Remove O.ORDER_ID from your GROUP BY

Comment: Yes, it Worked by removing O.ORDER_ID from GROUP BY, Thanks